# Sometimes xserver cannot open display at bootup

Tags: linux, xserver

We have a standard Yocto Poky distribution based on Linux kernel 3.10.38, that runs on an embedded screen. There is an QT application (GUI) installed which is booting up automatically at startup.

In general booting goes just fine, but one in a hundred times I get an xserver error:

```
xset: unable to open display ":0"<br>
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
```

After this the application tries to start, but exits with an error (because cannot connect to the display).

In the environment where this is used it is critical no boot ups get stuck. Is there any setting I can change or adding a wait and/or a retry regarding booting the xserver, to make it more robust?

Comment: Did this work after a reboot?

Comment: After a reboot it works again for many times, but after a while it crashes again.

Comment: How is the application "automatically" started?  As the application argument of `startx`?  Via a users `.xsession` file? Or by a separate init-system job, like a daemon?  If the last of those, you obviously have a race condition, and need to deal with it (e.g. with a simply retry loop).

Comment: Via a custom start script first "export DISLAY=:0" is executed and after that the application started.

Comment: Now added a 5 sec sleep before the export display command to make sure X is already started. Still the system crashed. Could my export display command triggered in my own startup script be a racing condition regarding to X server booting itself?